# How to protect my webapplication with wso2 identity server?

Tags: wso2

My requirement is to protect one webapplication(say mywebapp.com) with wso2 identity server. So whenever user will access mywebapp.com it will be authenticated against wso2IS.

How can I do that? I can't see any steps described for doing this. Where can I find the wso2IS agent to download for intercepting the request for mywebapp.com?

I have installed wso2 identity server and it is running. Here are my current tech stacks:

Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3
java version "1.6.0_29"
apache-activemq-5.8.0
wso2 identity server - 4.1.0

Is there anything I need to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following docs will give instructions on how to provide security for web apps through WSO2 IS..

[1] http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server

[2] http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2012/12/providing-xacml-fine-grained-authorization-webapps

[3] http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/11/getting-user-claims-over-saml-sso-token.html

Answer (score 0):

In the next wso2 release you can find a SSO tomcat agent for this scenario. now you can see it in:
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.tomcat.agent/ also read the readme file for the steps you need